# How to use linq with an aggregate , join and Group by

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get averages of restaurant Ratings  by id along with the Names 
of resteraunts.

**Review Class**

```
  public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        public double   Rating { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ResterauntId")]
        Resteraunt  Resteraunt { get; set; }
        public int ResterauntId { get; set; }
```

**Resteraunt class**

```
  public int ResterauntId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public virtual Review  reviews{ get; set; }
```

Here is what I tried. However this will not compile [g.Key.Rating.Average()]
And I don't know how to select the names without grouping by name as well

```
var ratings = (from rev in reviewsList
                 join res in resteraunts on rev.ResterauntId equals
                 res.ResterauntId

                 group new { rev, res } by new { res.ResterauntId, rev.Rating } into g

                 select new { Rating = g.Key.Rating, AveraRating =   g.Key.Rating.Average() }).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you know the type of `Key.Rating`? Do you see why you can't apply `Average`?

Comment: @NetMage It is a double type

Comment: So there is no `double.Average` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by restaurant (id) and average the ratings for each. Since LINQ has Group Join, you can just use the `join` to get the grouping:

```
var avgRatings = (from res in resteraunts
                  join rev in reviewsList on res.ResterauntId equals
                  rev.ResterauntId into revj
                  select new { res.ResterauntId, AveraRating = revj.Average(r => r.Rating) }).ToList();
```

Looking more closely at your (partial) classes, I see you are apparently using Entity Framework, in which case you don't need to manually join:

```
var avgRatings = (from res in resteraunts
                  select new {
                      res.ResterauntId,
                      AveraRating = res.Reviews.Average(r => (double?)r.Rating)
                  }).ToList();
```

Improvement on `Average` thanks to @gnud.

Comment: If your InvalidOperationException is saying 'the materialized value is null', this happens because some resturants have no reviews, and so there is no average. Replace the average call with `revj.Average(r => (double?)r.Rating)`, and the ones without any averages will have `AverageRating == null` (or cast to `int?` if your rating is an int)

Comment: @gnud Very nice. `Rating` is a double.